# change the default color of a ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot using a custom package fishtaco. Please download it here:
[download package](https://github.com/omanor/fishtaco-plot/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz)

```
install.packages("<path to downloaded package.tar.gz", repos = NULL,type="source")
library(FishTacoPlot)
p <- MultiFunctionTaxaContributionPlots(input_dir="<path_to_package>/examples", input_prefix="HMP_fishtaco",
input_taxa_taxonomy="<path_to_package>/examples/HMP_TAXONOMY.tab", sort_by="list", plot_type="bars",
input_function_filter_list=c("ko00020", "ko00540","ko02040"), add_predicted_da_markers=TRUE, add_original_da_markers=TRUE)
```

This gives a plot as follows:
[image: ggplot2 with very similar colors]

As visible from the plot it is very hard to distinguish between the shades of blue. Is there a way to modify the ggplot2 object p generated with the code above? I tried to add a manual color scale:

```
p + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "dodgerblue2", "antiquewhite", "aquamarine", so on for as many legend 
    variables))
```

But that did not change the default underlying color scheme. I can't change the package, but can I change the ggplot2 color?

Comment: You set a `color` scale but it looks like those colours would be `fill` values, so you would need `scale_fill_manual` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked!